# How to download a file, in Unix, whose index changes constantly?

Tags: regex, grep, wget

I use wget as part of script to fetch a URL eg. "www.myremoteurl.com/subpage/index-X.run", but X is a integer that keeps incrementing/changing breaking the script as the resource will not have existed.

Comment: what you wanna do when X not exist, stop or ignore? do X has a limited range ? or some rules while increment?

Comment: It's actually a jenkins build number, to be precise, so it will increment with time.

Answer (score 0):

ok, then, it's easy!, as you imaged

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {1..10}
do
    wget www.someurl/someindex-$i.run &
done
```

this would loop from 1 to 10 and ignore any failure, should be handy for some normal cases

Comment: thanks although this solution, for say index 100, will attempt to download the resource 100 times making several unnecessary requests.

Comment: yes, there aren't any detection or check url exist things involved, but if you would like to clear the non exist empty page, you could check $? to get the return value of wget